MUI Sparkline: show the showHighligh always and with different colors based on condition
I have a sparkline chart from MUI for react as follows
import * as React from 'react';
import Stack from '@mui/material/Stack';
import Box from '@mui/material/Box';
import { SparkLineChart } from '@mui/x-charts/SparkLineChart';

export default function BasicSparkLine() {
  return (
    <Stack direction="row" sx={{ width: '100%' }}>
      <Box sx={{ flexGrow: 1 }}>
            <SparkLineChart
              data={[10, 20 , 30, 40, 0, -10, 25]}
              xAxis={{
                scaleType: 'point',
                data: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8],
              }}
              height={100}
              width={600}
              showHighlight
            />
      </Box>
    </Stack>
  );
}

If "showHighlight" is set to true, on hover of the sparkline chart, we can see a highlight coming on the chart on each xaxis point.
Q1: Is there a way to have those highlighted points always shown ?
Q2: IS there a possibility to show the highlighted points in different colors based on the xaxis value of that exact point
Any help or suggestion is much appreciated. Thanks in advance
Thanks,

For anyone who are having similar issues. I came to know that we can use the <Indicator /> to achieve this. Adding the same code as well.
import * as React from "react";
import Stack from "@mui/material/Stack";
import Box from "@mui/material/Box";
import { SparkLineChart } from "@mui/x-charts/SparkLineChart";
import {
  useXScale,
  useYScale,
  unstable_useLineSeries
} from "@mui/x-charts/hooks";

function Indicator({ dataIndex }: { dataIndex: number }) {
  const xScale = useXScale();
  const yScale = useYScale();
  const lineSeries = unstable_useLineSeries();

  const yData = lineSeries.series[lineSeries.seriesOrder[0]].data;
  const xData = xScale.domain();

  const xValue = xData[dataIndex];
  const yValue = yData[dataIndex];
  return (
    <circle
      cx={xScale(xValue)}
      cy={yScale(yValue)}
      r={5}
      fill={yValue > 4 ? "green" : "red"}
    />
  );
}
export default function BasicSparkLine() {
  return (
    <Stack direction="row" sx={{ width: "100%" }}>
      <Box sx={{ width: 300 }}>
        <SparkLineChart
          plotType="line"
          data={[1, 4, 2, 5, 7, 2, 4, 6]}
          height={100}
        >
        {[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7].map((tNew) => (
          <Indicator dataIndex={tNew} />
        ))}
        </SparkLineChart>
      </Box>
    </Stack>
  );
}


